# How to disable DPI scaling in wxWebview in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, webview2

I am working with the wxWebView of wxWidgets 3.2.1 in Windows 10. I am also using the Edge backend (WebView2). I have a problem in High DPI monitors and that's the automatic scaling of the Edge. I don't want this automatic scaling and prefer to set the font size manually with the use of some helpful functions like [`FromDIP`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a4b0a9da72d28465bdf5c0bfe5661cdf9). Apparently setting font does not work in this case.

I have seen a way to disable this feature in Chrome by command options like below ([Ref](https://superuser.com/questions/1189725/disable-chrome-scaling)) but don't know how to do this in wxWidgets.

`--high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=1`

Update: In the source of the page, I have a style tag and font is set there and I have the ability to change this font on DPI change event. Currently I don't change the font on the event.

Comment: what's wrong with automatic scaling?

Comment: @Igor I set the font scale in a CSS file. The automatic scaling scale that font for me which is wrong and it is bigger. If I want to use the automatic scale, I have to change that hard-coded font size in CSS by the DPI factor and then automatic scaling works!

Comment: what CSS file you are talking about? Is it some kind of HTML/XML file you are using for the page? Or its something you set the parameters of the browser? If its the latter and you have control over it - why do you need the calculation yourself?

Comment: If that file is in use because you are using IE and Edge backends - drop it. IE is going away really soon and it will not be supported by MS anymore. I suggest to get rid of all hacks yuo did to support both and leave only the Edge support.

Comment: @Igor I have updated the question. I don't use IE backend

Comment: do you have control over the page source? If not - can you contact the author of the page? My point is - if the automatic scaling works - why not use it. It's possible the code for page was done a long time ago and is irrelevant now when HighDPI is everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is not any way to disable scaling feature in Edge via wxWidgets. Therefore because of this automatic upscaling in Edge, I had to downscale my font size first with the use of [`GetDPIScaleFactor()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a43bfd56d59b728157f95c838f981872c).